# Redirect the output to a file with date format name using crontab & nohup

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, nohup

Now I have a script `start.sh` to start my application:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:~/log4j.xml -Xmx2048m -jar ~/myapp.jar
```

And I add this script to `crontab` to make it as a schedule job:

```
15 05 * * 1-5 /home/me/start.sh >> /home/me/cronlog/$(date +"\%F")-start.log 2>&1
```

which redirects the output of `start.sh` to a separate file with date format name

Right now, I'd like use `nohup` and put the redirect command to the `start.sh` script rather than in `crontab`

So the `crontab` looks clean:

```
15 05 * * 1-5 /home/me/start.sh
```

And in the `start.sh`, after testing it should be:

```
nohup java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:~/log4j.xml -Xmx2048m -jar ~/myapp.jar > ~/cronlog/$(date +"%F")-nohup.log 2>&1 &
```

Here is my question:

1. Why in `crontab`, backslash `\` is needed but in the new `start.sh` script, it isn't needed?
2. I'd like to record every output to the file including exception or error, should it ends with up `2>&1 &`. The last `&` is from `nohup`. So what exactly do the `2>&1` and '&` mean?

Comment: with crontab you can't use ~, it's for your users home directory not for crontabs

Comment: @tanaydin Thanks for pointing out. In reality, `~` isn't used. I put `~` in `crontab` here for easy description.

Comment: I kind of doubt it. Is `\ ` really needed there?

Comment: `date +"\%F"` will put a literal backslash in the name. You probably don't want the backslash. This produces, e.g. `\2014-08-15`. You don't really need the quotes, either -- this will work `$(date +%F)`.

Answer (score 0):

2>&1 means "redirect standard error on standard output"

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

As you can see in that page, the numebers refer to the file descriptors used by the OS to point the resources (stderr, stdout), and &> is a redirection operator.